# Args for sb-ext:run-program

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

Can someone tell me exactly what the args argument should look like for [sb-ext:run-program](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Running-external-programs)?

If I do this:

```
(sb-ext:run-program "C:/Program Files/iTunes/iTunes.exe" 
               "C:/lispbox-0.7/opus.mid")
```

I get this error:

```
debugger invoked on a TYPE-ERROR:
  The value "C:/lispbox-0.7/opus.mid" is not of type LIST.
```

However, if I do this:

```
(sb-ext:run-program "C:/Program Files/iTunes/iTunes.exe" 
               (list "C:\lispbox-0.7\opus.mid"))
```

iTunes opens, but the MIDI file doesn't play, even though this invocation from the Windows command prompt works just fine:

```
U:\>"C:\Program Files\iTunes\iTunes.exe" C:\lispbox-0.7\opus.mid
```

Note that this (with forward slashes):

```
CL-USER> (sb-ext:run-program "C:/Program Files/iTunes/iTunes.exe" 
               (list "C:/lispbox-0.7/opus.mid"))
```

has the same effect: iTunes opens, but the file is not played.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the list version you're using single backslashes, which get parsed as escape sequences. You need to use double backslashes.

Comment: Yes, you were right.  Double back-slashes worked (but forward slashes didn't).