# How can you use parameters in sbcl (common-lisp), for sb-ext:run-program?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I'm trying to call an external shell command in common-lisp, via SBCL's sb-ext:run-program.

Documentation about this run-program command, can be found here:
http://sbcl.org/manual/index.html
in the section
*7.7.3 Running external programs*

That page, does not contain examples. I figured out how to use it, by checking this page:
[stackoverflow examples for sb-ext:run-program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065446/executing-a-shell-command-from-common-lisp#6066206)

This is what I'm trying to do...

First, I define a variable for a parameter:

```
(defconstant *a-argument* "-lh")
```

Then I call a command:

```
(sb-ext:run-program "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Gow\\bin\\ls.exe"
                    '(*a-argument*)
                    :output *standard-output*)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
debugger invoked on a TYPE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {100299C8F3}>:
  The value
    *A-ARGUMENT*
  is not of type
    SEQUENCE
```

However, if I call it like this:

```
(sb-ext:run-program "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Gow\\bin\\ls.exe"
                    '("-lh")
                    :output *standard-output*)
```

then it works. The only difference is using `"-lh"` directly, instead of `*a-argument*`.

So the question I have is:
*What do I need to do, to make the run-program call work, with a variable in the parameter list?*

Extra info:

```
windows32 2.6.1 7601 i686-pc Intel unknown MinGW
SBCL 1.3.8
```

But I also tested this on FreeBSD 10.1 and there I have the same problem.

Comment: `'(*a-argument*)` is a quoted list containing the symbol `*a-argument*`, not the value of the variable by that name (remember that the contents of quoted lists are not evaluated). You need to use `(list *a-argument*)`.

Comment: I tried that, but it seems to evaluate each symbol seperately... giving me the following error: `(sb-ext:run-program "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Gow\\bin\\ls.exe" '("-lh" (list *a-argument*)) :output *standard-output*)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Gow\bin\ls.exe: (LIST: No such file or directory
C:\Program Files (x86)\Gow\bin\ls.exe: *A-ARGUMENT*): Invalid argument`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see what you mean now... that does seem to work. Thanks @jkiiski.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Args for sb-ext:run-program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078448/args-for-sb-extrun-program)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was given by jkiiski:

I needed to change this call:

```
(sb-ext:run-program "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Gow\\bin\\ls.exe"
                    '(*a-argument*)
                    :output *standard-output*)
```

To this call:

```
(sb-ext:run-program "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Gow\\bin\\ls.exe"
                    (list *a-argument*)
                    :output *standard-output*)
```